# Error with jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I get an error with my custom plugin, as a beginner to this. I am trying to change the properties of divs on a page.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.changeDiv = function( options ) {

    var settings = $.extend({
        // These are the defaults.
        text  : 'Hello, World!',
        color: "#556b2f",
        backgroundColor: "white",
        borderColor : "white",
        borderWeight: "1px;",
        fontWeight   : 'bold',
        fontStyle   : 'Trebuchet MS, Callibri, Sans-Serif',
        fontSize  : '18px',
        position: "center",
        fl : "auto",
        wt: "auto",
        ht: "auto",
        mRight: "auto",
        mLeft: "auto",
        complete : null
    }, options );
            return this.each( function() {

         $(this).text( settings.text );

        if ( settings.color ) {
            $(this).css( 'color', settings.color );
        }

        if ( settings.fontStyle ) {
            $(this).css( 'font-style', settings.fontStyle );
        }

        if ( settings.fontWeight ) {
            $(this).css( 'font-weight', settings.fontWeight );
        }

        if ( settings.fontSize ) {
            $(this).css( 'font-size', settings.fontSize );
        }

        if ( settings.wt ) {
            $(this).css( 'width', settings.wt );
        }

        if ( settings.ht ) {
            $(this).css( 'height', settings.ht );
        }

        if ( settings.position ) {
            $(this).css( 'text-align', settings.position );
        }

        if ( settings.fl ) {
            $(this).css( 'float', settings.fl );
        }

        if ( settings.mRight ) {
            $(this).css( 'margin-right', settings.mRight );
        }

        if ( settings.mLeft ) {
            $(this).css( 'margin-left', settings.mLeft );
        }

        if ( $.isFunction( settings.complete ) ) {
            settings.complete.call( this );
        }
  });
};
```

I am using this when call the function :

```
$('#header').changeDiv({
text: 'This is the header div',
    fontStyle: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif',
fontWeight: 'bold',
backgroundColor: '#406481',
fontSize: '30px',
ht: "50px",
position: "center",
complete    : function() { $(this).easeIn("slow",1500); }
});
```

The result I get is only the text 'This is the header div' with green color and the alignment of central. If I apply the same changeDiv function to the menu, nothing happens. If I change the return function to the following:

```
return this.css({
    color: settings.color,
    backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor,
    borderColor: settings.backgroundColor,
    borderWeight: settings.borderWeight,
fontWeight: settings.fontWeight,
fontStyle: settings.fontStyle,
fontSize: settings.fontSize,
position: settings.position,
fl: settings.fl,
wt: settings.wt,
ht: settings.ht,
mRight:settings.mRight,
mLeft: settings.mLeft
});
```

I can see in FireBug the styles are applied to the divs, but the default text does not change.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is in the `css` you try to write. `fontStyle` has to be `font-family`.

try this:

```
$(this).css( 'font-family', settings.fontStyle );
```

**edit**

The question is already solved: an working example for other people trying to find an answer:

Added $ in line 1 and made some changes to the original code

http://jsfiddle.net/e5HHc/1/

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. I want to REPLACE the Hello Wolrd text bwith what I call in he header, menu or other divs.

Comment: Sorry, didn't got that! If i understand it corectly it works on #header but doesnt work on an other div ?

Comment: Yes, that's what's strange.

Comment: I also added .html(settings.text).settings.complete.call( this ) to the return code, that diaplayed the text I wanted in the header. Other divs don't work.

Comment: I put my function in a file called jquery.changeDiv;js and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the $.fn.changeDiv in

```
    $(function($) {
```

So you need the $ character. (in your 1st line) And when you call it the chageDiv, use also this definition. It works for me in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/system7/KTFDT/).